# If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$ then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have looked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676333/prove-that-if-ranka-n-then-rankab-rankb), but still I cannot understand how to get to equality.
Let assume that the matrices are squared

$\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \operatorname{rank}(B)$ is easy to show, but how can I show $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(AB)$?

Comment: You haven't said what $n$ is in this question. Is $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in the question I referred to it was proven for none square matrices

Comment: You should still strive to create self-contained questions. There are two goals on this site: (1) To answer your question, and (2) to remain as a useful resource to others who find this question and its answers. For (2), we strive to keep the questions self-contained.  @gbox

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I will try to apply it from now

Answer (score 4):

Assuming $A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix, to say that $A$ has rank $n$ is equivalent to saying that the $n$ columns of $A$ are linearly independent, which in turn is equivalent to saying that $A$ has kernel $\{0\}$. This means $A$ is one-to-one.

Hence in particular $A$ is one-to-one on the range of $B$, a space of dimension $rank(B)$. Hence the range of $AB$ also has dimension $rank(B)$. So $rank(AB) = rank(B)$.

Comment: Is there a way to prove it using the Row/column Span?

Comment: I guess you can replace "range of $B$" by "span of the columns of $B$" and so on but I think that would make the argument harder to understand.

Answer (score 3):

$$\operatorname{rank}(AB)\ge \operatorname{rank}(A^{-1}AB)$$

Comment: I can do it because elementary matrices do not change the Rank?

Comment: Does $A$ have to be a square matrix though?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the question linked to above does not state that $A$ is $n\times n$, only $m\times n$. So there is a left-inverse, but it isn't called $A^{-1}$...

Comment: Well, if $n$ occurs in a matrix problem without further mention, I thought it safe to assume that $n=\dim V$ ...