# What all possible matrix reprsentations a linear operator can have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

$L$ is a linear operator such that $L:V \to V$ where $V$ is a $n$ dimensional hilbert space. If $[L]_{ij}$ is the matrix representation for $L$ in the input and output basis $\{i\}$ and $\{j\}$, then what is common in all the matrices $[L]_{ij}$  for varying $\{i\}$ and $\{j\}$. I feel they all have the same rank ( if I am not wrong ) but can't prove it definitely.

Comment: Yeah they have same rank/determinant, trace, eigenvalues...

Comment: To summarize, they have the same [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

Comment: @Joelafrite trace is same if input output basis are same ( same goes for eigen values ) am i correct ?

Comment: Oh, I see, you're allowing for a different input and output basis. Then trace is the only invariant; you can always find a pair of input/output bases so that the resulting matrix is just $t$ one's down the diagonal, where $t$ is the rank.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein so rank and trace both are invariant ?

Comment: My bad, not trace. Just rank.

Comment: e.g. $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ has rank $1$, but trace $0$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein yeah I was also just doubtful about that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the matrix is $A_L$ in some basis (e.g. the standard basis) $\{e_i\}$. Say your input basis is $\{f_i\}$ and your output basis is $\{d_i\}$. Let the base change matrix from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{f_i\}$ be $T_f$ and the base change matrix from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{d_i\}$ be $T_d$, then you can do the following, given a vector $x_f$ in your input basis:

- Convert $x_f$ from $\{f_i\}$ to $\{e_i\}$: $x_e = T_f^{-1} x_f$.
- Apply $A_L$: $y_e = A_Lx_e = A_LT_f^{-1}x_f$.
- Convert $y_e$ from $\{e_i\}$ to $\{d_i\}$: $y_d = T_dy_e = T_dA_LT_f^{-1}x_f$.

I.e. you have
$$[L]_{f,d} = T_dA_LT_f^{-1}$$
since $T_d$ and $T_f$ both have full rank, we immediately get
$$\operatorname{rank} [L]_{f,d} = \operatorname{rank} A_L$$
from [well-known properties of rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676333/prove-that-if-ranka-n-then-rankab-rankb), i.e. the rank is independent of $f$ and $d$.

Other properties, e.g. the determinant will not be independent of $f$ and $d$:
$$\det [L]_{f,d} = \det T_d \det A_L \frac{1}{\det T_f}$$
but if you constrain $f$ and $d$ to be orthonormal bases, it will be the same up to a sign difference.

This question is basically asking what properties of linear transformations are invariant under the [action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of the product of the [general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group), $GL(V) \times GL(V)$ defined by
$$(g_1, g_2) \cdot L = g_1 L g_2^{-1}.$$

Comment: thanks for a concrete answer but could you give a link or hint to the proof for the property of rank you mentioned ?

Comment: @sasha I added a link in the answer.